# R spineplot: how are breaks for contious variable chosen?

Tags: r, plot

The *spineplot* function in R uses some magic to split a continuous range into cells, e.g. *Sepal.Length* in

```
spineplot(Species ~ Sepal.Length, data=iris)
```

Unfortunately, the documentation provides no hints how this is done. There is a *breaks* parameter, but it is not said how it is chosen automatically.

Does someone know the rule?

Comment: `breaks` is the same as `breaks` of the `hist` function. You can either set breakpoints or create your own function for discretization. It uses the sturges rule by default.

Comment: @sanlooo The Sturges rule creates equally spaced cells. Is this also done for spineplots and the apparent uneven spaceing is unrelated to the discretization, but due to the area representing proportions?

Comment: Seems that it only accepts the number of (equally spaced) breaks: https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/library/graphics/R/spineplot.R#L121